# How to write the below given shorted set in Redis

Tags: redis

How to write the below in Redis

"Create a sorted set myset1 with the following values ( 1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3 , 'c').Create a sorted set myset 2 with the following values (4, 'b', 1, 'c', 0, 'd').Find the intersection of myset1 and myset2 : - Write a command to find the intersection of myset1 and myset2 and store the intersection in out- Write a command to see the resulting intersection output Sorted set "out" : Find the union of myset1 and myset2 - Write a command to take the union of myset1 and myset2 and store the output in unout - Write a command to see the resulting intersection output Sorted set "unout" "

I wrote the code like below and it says 80% correct.

127.0.0.1:6379> zadd myset1 0 1 0 a 0 2 0 b 0 3 0 c (integer) 6 127.0.0.1:6379> zadd myset2 0 4 0 b 0 1 0 c 0 0 0 d (integer) 6 127.0.0.1:6379> zinterstore out 2 myset1 myset2 (integer) 3 127.0.0.1:6379> zrange out 0 -1 1) "1" 2) "b" 3) "c" 127.0.0.1:6379> zunionstore unout 2 myset1 myset2 (integer) 9 127.0.0.1:6379> zrange unout 0 -1 1) "0" 2) "1" 3) "2" 4) "3" 5) "4" 6) "a" 7) "b" 8) "c" 9) "d" 127.0.0.1:6379>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ZINTERSTORE` and `ZUNIONSTORE`  commands to computer intersection and union of intersection of sorted sets.

[ZINTERSTORE](https://redis.io/commands/zinterstore)

**ZINTERSTORE destination numkeys key [key ...] [WEIGHTS weight [weight ...]] [AGGREGATE SUM|MIN|MAX]**

> Computes the intersection of numkeys sorted sets given by the
> specified keys, and stores the result in destination. It is mandatory
> to provide the number of input keys (numkeys) before passing the input
> keys and the other (optional) arguments.
>
> By default, the resulting score of an element is the sum of its scores
> in the sorted sets where it exists. Because intersection requires an
> element to be a member of every given sorted set, this results in the
> score of every element in the resulting sorted set to be equal to the
> number of input sorted sets.

[ZUNIONSTORE](https://redis.io/commands/zunionstore)

**ZUNIONSTORE destination numkeys key [key ...] [WEIGHTS weight [weight ...]] [AGGREGATE SUM|MIN|MAX]**

> Computes the union of numkeys sorted sets given by the specified keys,
> and stores the result in destination. It is mandatory to provide the
> number of input keys (numkeys) before passing the input keys and the
> other (optional) arguments.
>
> By default, the resulting score of an element is the sum of its scores
> in the sorted sets where it exists.

Edit:
It's not accepting since you're adding score as key as well

Yout `ZADD` commands should be

```
ZADD myset1 1, a 2 b 3  c
zadd myset2  4  b  1  c   0 d
```

Comment: I tried both but I am not able to clear this question it is giving error. could you please write the exact command so i can clear this question.

Comment: @TheSteepCoinSingapore sorry! I'm not here to solve the issue, I'm just here to guide you how to get something working.

Comment: Thanks  for checking I have write the code like below and it says 80% correct.                     127.0.0.1:6379> zadd myset1 0 1 0 a 0 2 0 b 0 3 0 c
(integer) 6
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd myset2 0 4 0 b 0 1 0 c 0 0 0 d
(integer) 6
127.0.0.1:6379> zinterstore out 2 myset1 myset2
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange out 0 -1
1) "1"
2) "b"
3) "c"
127.0.0.1:6379> zunionstore unout 2 myset1 myset2
(integer) 9
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange unout 0 -1
1) "0"
2) "1"
3) "2"
4) "3"
5) "4"
6) "a"
7) "b"
8) "c"
9) "d"
127.0.0.1:6379>

Comment: If it helped then you can upvote or accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ZADD myset1 1 a 2 b 3 c

ZADD myset2 4 b 1 c 0 d

ZINTERSTORE out 2 myset1 myset2

ZUNIONSTORE unout 2 myset1 myset2
```